# В чем проблема? Embed Error

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

столкнулся с такой проблемой то что не выводится embed discord.py с чем может быть связано?

Ошибок никаких нету вообще

код:

@client.command()
async def verif(ctx):

```
emb = discord.Embed(
    description = 
    f"""
    Здраствуйте вы попали на сервер {ctx.guild.name}, пройдите верификацию чтобы получить доступ к другим каналам.
    """,
    colour = 0xFF8C00
)
emb.set_thumbnail(url = 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/772850448892690462/880752123418136596/947d1f802c858b540b84bc3000fc2439_1_-removebg-preview.png')
emb.set_author(name = 'Верификация')

row = ActionRow(
    Button(
        style = ButtonStyle.gray,
        label = 'Верифицироваться',
        custom_id = 'verif_button'
    ),
    Button(
        style = ButtonStyle.gray,
        label = 'Верифицироваться2',
        custom_id = 'verif_button2'
    )
)
await ctx.send(embed = emb, components = [row])
```

Comment: Прикрепите код эмбеда.

Comment: @client.command()
async def verif(ctx):

    emb = discord.Embed(
        description = 
        f"""
        Здраствуйте вы попали на сервер {ctx.guild.name}, пройдите верификацию чтобы получить доступ к другим каналам.
        """,
        colour = 0xFF8C00
    )
    emb.set_thumbnail(url = 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/772850448892690462/880752123418136596/947d1f802c858b540b84bc3000fc2439_1_-removebg-preview.png')
    emb.set_author(name = 'Верификация')
    await ctx.send(embed = emb, components = [row])

Comment: Используйте кнопку править в вашем сообщении, не нужно в комментарии кидать код, неразбериха полная

Comment: Окей, но у меня только кнопки появляются. Вот когда я ставлю на хостинг всё отлично работает. А вот на моем компьютере нету эмбеда, только одни кнопки.